# jQuery - Extract name of class based on prefix

Tags: jquery

I'm using WordPress and I need to get part of a class name stored in the body tag.

I would like to extract word(s) after `post-type` prefix.

```
<body class="post-php post-type-dissertation is-fullscreen-mode wp-embed-responsive customize-support svg">
<body class="post-php post-type-subject-imposed is-fullscreen-mode wp-embed-responsive customize-support svg">
```

In my examples I would like to get `dissertation` or `subject-imposed` after `post-type` prefix.

With my code I get all classes after `post-type`

```
var $cn = jQuery('body[class*="post-type"]').attr('class');
console.log($cn.split('post-type-')[1]);
```

Example of output :

```
dissertation is-fullscreen-mode wp-embed-responsive customize-support svg
```

How can I delete all others classes and keep `dissertation` or `subject-imposed` words ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cn = jQuery('body[class*="post-type"]').attr('class');

finder = 'post-type'
my_str = ''
cn.split(' ').forEach(function(item) {
  if(item.indexOf(finder) != -1){
    my_str = item.split('-').splice(2, 2).join('-')
    
  }
});

console.log(my_str)
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for your help. That's works fine. You have tested each classes in body tag. The correct class was splited and splice after 2 first words and join the others words right ?

Comment: Yes, I was in hurry that time so I couldn't explain it.  I am checking each class one by one if substr contains. Once we got it we can break the loop also. And then removing substr using splice function.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all classes then *split* them to convert them as array then loop through all classes and check if it has `post-type` in it or not depending on this remove class .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var $cn = jQuery('body').attr('class').split(/\s+/); //split..
console.log("BEFORE :  " + jQuery('body').attr('class'))
$($cn).each(function(i) {
  //check if has value..
  if ($cn[i].indexOf("post-type") < 0) {
    jQuery('body').removeClass($cn[i]) //remove class...
  }
})
console.log("AFTER :" + jQuery('body').attr('class').split('post-type-')[1])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="post-php post-type-dissertation is-fullscreen-mode wp-embed-responsive customize-support svg">
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is a solution

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is get all class as one string.
Then split the classes into an array of class.
Loop through the class array and search for the your desired text.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var body_class = $('body').attr('class');
  var class_array = body_class.split(' ');
  class_array.forEach(function(ele) {
    if (ele.search("post-type-") != -1) {
      console.log(ele);
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="post-php post-type-subject-imposed is-fullscreen-mode wp-embed-responsive customize-support svg">
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery helps you a lot here. No need to process the elements individually, as jQuery can handle them all in one go:

```js
// $(".post-type-dissertation,.post-type-subject-imposed") // clear only for selected divs
   $("div[class*=post-type]") // clear for all divs with class = post type... 

     .attr("class",(i,cls)=>cls.match(/\b(post-type-(dissertation|subject-imposed))\b/g)||[].join(" "));

   $("div").each(function(){console.log(this.className)});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post-php post-type-dissertation is-fullscreen-mode wp-embed-responsive customize-support svg">dissertation</div>
<div class="post-php post-type-subject-imposed is-fullscreen-mode wp-embed-responsive customize-support svg">subject imposed</div>
<div class="post-php post-type-something-else is-fullscreen-mode wp-embed-responsive customize-support svg">something else</div>
<div class="post-php post-type-and-this-too is-fullscreen-mode wp-embed-responsive customize-support svg">and this too</div>
```

In the sample above I replaced `body` by `div` as you cannot have multiple bodies in an SO snippet.

Depending on whether you want to clear away the other classes for all divs or only for those where the search classes can be found, you can adapt the first selector to "div". That would leave the last two divs without any classes.